# R shortcut to getting last n entries in a vector

Tags: arrays, r, vector, indexing

This may be redundant but I could not find a similar question on SO.

Is there a shortcut to getting the last *n* elements/entries in a vector or array *without using the length* of the vector in the calculation?

`foo <- 1:23`

```
> foo
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

Let say one wants the last 7 entities, I want to avoid this cumbersome syntax:

```
> foo[(length(foo)-6):length(foo)]
[1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

Python has `foo[-7:]`. Is there something similar in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want the `tail` function

```
foo <- 1:23
tail(foo, 5)
#[1] 19 20 21 22 23
tail(foo, 7)
#[1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
x <- 1:3
# If you ask for more than is currently in the vector it just
# returns the vector itself.
tail(x, 5)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Along with `head` there are easy ways to grab everything *except* the last/first n elements of a vector as well.

```
x <- 1:10
# Grab everything except the first element
tail(x, -1)
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# Grab everything except the last element
head(x, -1)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Plus one and wanted to note the nice negative indexing properties of `tail` and `head` for future searchers. You can say "Give me all but the last n elements/rows" as wel: `head(foo, -2)`

Comment: @TylerRinker Good point - that is good info and I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea when you have the awesome tail function but here's an alternative:

```
n <- 3
rev(rev(foo)[1:n])
```

I'm preparing myself for the down votes.

Comment: +1 for clever use of of `rev`. Also avoids using length(foo). Why can't R use `len` instead of `length` like Python?! Saves 50% typing.

Comment: I like the first one but the second one was explicitly what they were trying to avoid in the original question.

Comment: @Dason good point I removed it as the poster explicitly states their disdain for length.

Comment: @rmk - You could always do `len <- length` if you really wanted to save typing those 3 characters every time